# Extracting titles from a text

Tags: python

I'm working on a project, where I have to extract honorific titles (Mr, Mrs, St, etc.) from a novel. The desired output with the text I'm working with is:

```
['Col', 'Dr', 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Otto', 'Rev', 'St']
```

However, with the code I wrote, the output is this:

```
{'Tom.', 'Mrs.', 'Otto.', 'Mary.', 'Bots.', 'Come.', 'No.', 'Col.', 'Cain.', 'Dr.', 'Gang.', 'Ike.', 'Kean.', 'St.', 'Hank.', 'Him.', 'Finn.', 'Ann.', 'Jane.', 'Alas.', 'Huck.', 'Sis.', 'Buck.', 'Jim.', 'Sid.', 'Mr.', 'Bill.', 'Rev.', 'Yes.'}
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
def get_titles(text):
  pattern = re.compile('[A-Z][a-z]{1,3}\.')
  title_tokens = set(re.findall(pattern, text))
  pattern2 = re.compile('[A-Z][a-z]{1,3}')
  pseudo_titles = set(re.findall(pattern2, text))

  pseudo_titles = [word.strip() for word in pseudo_titles]
  pseudo_titles = [word.replace('\n', '') for word in pseudo_titles]

  difference = title_tokens.difference(pseudo_titles)
  return difference 

test = get_titles(text)
print(test)
```

As you can notice, the output gives me additional words with periods in them. I believe the issue stems from the regular expressions, but I'm not sure. Any advice or tips are appreciated.

The text can be found here: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-0.txt

Comment: I can't think of an easy way to distinguish honorifics from other abbreviations (Dr. and Col. compared to Ave. and No., for example). Rather than going with regex, can you just create a list of honorifics to search for? Or does that defeat the purpose of the exercise? Looking at the text, the only distinction I can see between honorifics and sentence ends is that honorifics are structured [chars].[space][chars], whereas sentence ends are [chars].-- or [chars].[space][space]. You could try building that into your regex.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you are asking for an algorithm which can tell the difference between a title and one-word sentence. These are lexically indistinguishable; for example, consider the following two strings:

- "Do I know who did this? Yes. Smith did it."
- "Do I know who did this? Mr. Smith did it."

In the first sentence, "Yes." is a one-word sentence, and in the second, "Mr." is a title. As humans we only know this because we understand the meanings of the tokens "Yes" and "Mr"; so an algorithm which is able to distinguish between these cases requires some information about the meanings of the tokens it's parsing. It cannot work purely lexically like a regex does. This means you must either write a whitelist of allowed titles, or a blacklist of words which are not titles, or otherwise the problem is much more difficult.

Alternatively, if your project doesn't involve parsing titles from very many novels, you could just trim down the results by hand, using your human knowledge that "Tom" and "Yes" aren't titles. It shouldn't be that much work.